# JdbcIO.readAll not firing results

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm working with Apache Beam, trying to enrich data (based on [this](https://medium.com/@tnymltn/enrichment-pipeline-patterns-using-apache-beam-4b9b81e5d9f3)), but it seems that Beam has changed in a while, as GroupByKey does not work with unbounded sources (like PubSub) without windowing.

This is what I've got (overly simplified):

```
PCollection<String> input = pipeline.apply("Read pubsub", 
    PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getInputTopic()))
        .apply("Log element", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                System.out.println(String.format("incomig %s", c.element()));
                c.output(c.element());
            }
        }))
        .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(5))));

PCollection<KV<String, String>> incomingData = input
       .apply("Apply Random Key", MapElements
                       .via(new SimpleFunction<String, KV<String, String>>() {
                           public KV<String, String> apply(String json) {
                               JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                               System.out.println(String.format("JSON: %s, %s", jsonObject.getString("id"), jsonObject.get("usageRules")));
                               return KV.of(jsonObject.getString("id"), json);
                           }
                       })
       );

PCollection<KV<String,String>> enrichedData = incomingData
        .apply("Search in db",
                JdbcIO.<KV<String,String>, KV<String,String>>readAll()
                        .withDataSourceConfiguration(config)
                        .withQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = ?")
                        .withParameterSetter((element, preparedStatement) ->
                                preparedStatement.setString(1, element.getKey())
                        )
                        .withRowMapper(resultSet -> {
                            System.out.println(String.format("Result from db: %s", resultSet.getString("id")));
                            return KV.of(resultSet.getString("id"), resultSet.getString("id"));
                        })
                        .withCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of())));



GroupByKey.applicableTo(enrichedData);
TupleTag<String> CREATE_TAG = new TupleTag<>();
TupleTag<String> UPDATE_TAG = new TupleTag<>();

KeyedPCollectionTuple
        .of(CREATE_TAG, incomingData)
        .and(UPDATE_TAG, enrichedData)
        .apply("Combine", CoGroupByKey.create())
        .apply("Show data?", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, CoGbkResult>, String>() {
           @ProcessElement
           public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
               System.out.println("Print from CoGbkResult");
               System.out.println(context.element().getKey());
               System.out.println(context.element().getValue());
           }
        }));
```

At the moment, with windowing, getting incoming data, transforming it into JSONObject and searching in BD is working fine, the problem is that any .apply done after the JdbcIO.readAll is not working at all. The line "Print from CoGbkResult" just doesn't get printed at all.

I've tried modifying the window, adding other triggers, trying just to output a result just immediately, but it just stop at the RowMapper.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just confirming, but the printlns in the `JdbcIO.readAll` transform are output correctly, right? Only the logs in the CoGroupByKey are missing? And when you tried outputting the result immediately, you just added a ParDo immediately after the `readAll` that logged each element?

Comment: Just thought of this but maybe Beam's fusion optimization (see ParDo's [optimization section](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.28.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.html)) is being overly aggressive and removing the last ParDo there. If that's the case, adding a sink afterwards (like [`TextIO`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.28.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html)) would fix it.

Comment: @DanielOliveira as you say, the println "Resul from db: %s" is correctly printed. Any other transformation applied to `enrichedData` is ignored and not processed, and that includes the `KeyedPCollectionTuple`.  Addind a Sink immediately after reading bd would not suffice my use case where I need to group result to know whether to update or insert a record in the Bd (Basically a find, insert if not exists, update if exists like flow)

Comment: The sink suggestion can just be for debugging. If the optimizer is being overly-aggressive, it might see that the ParDo's output is not being consumed, decide that there is no reason to run the ParDo, and therefore the printlns never get executed. Adding another transform consuming the output of your println transform would avoid this issue. It might not even need to be a sink, a Reshuffle transform might work too. This is just to test if my theory is correct, I don't know for sure if it'll work.

Comment: @DanielOliveira thanks for your debugging inside, but sadly it didn't work. After the CoGroupByKey, I formed a new string (to consume the grouped output) and write to a pubsub topic (just to avoid the unbounded PCollection), but nothing get published nor printed.